# Bootstrap dropdown is not full width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap dropdown for some reason is nowhere near full width and I need it to be.

Here is an image of what Im talking about:

[image]

The country and city are bootstrap dropdowns which I have styled rather a lot to completely change the look. They are each inside a container row. They each take up 6 columns so that it is split in half. I just want them to take up their full half of the green bit. Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<div id="find-vegan-products-page" style="height:900px;">
  <div class="form-background">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 40px;">
      <h1>Filter Your Search!</h1>
      <form role="form">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle input-control no-box-shadow" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Country
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">HTML</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle input-control no-box-shadow" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">City
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">HTML</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.input-control {
    height: 5rem;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid dimgray;
    border-left-style: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
button.input-control:hover {
    background-color: none;
    background: none;
}
.btn-primary.active,
.btn-primary:active,
.open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    /* color: #fff; */

    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}
.btn:focus,
.btn:active {
    outline: none !important;
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: dimgray;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-primary.active.focus, .btn-primary.active:focus, .btn-primary.active:hover, .btn-primary:active.focus, .btn-primary:active:focus, .btn-primary:active:hover, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary.focus, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:focus, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: dimgray;
}

.btn {
    font-weight: 100;
}


.btn-primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: dimgray;
}

dropdown > button {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}



.form-background {
    background: rgba(149, 246, 102, .5);
}

#find-vegan-products-page {
margin-top: 100px; /*separate the div from top of the page*/
padding: 100px; /*or whatever value to give the div space */
}

.btn.btn-default:focus {
border:none;
outline:0;

}

.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    white;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.form-control:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    white;
   opacity:  1;
   font-weight: 100;
}
.form-control::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    white;
   opacity:  1;
   font-weight: 100;
}
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color:    white;
   font-weight: 100;
}
.form-control:placeholder-shown { /* Standard (https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#placeholder) */
  color:    white;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

How do I make the bootstrap dropdowns take up their full 6 columns in the bootstrap container? The only thing that will look different will be the bottom border will go the full width of the 6 container columns.

Comment: Try without your `padding:40px` style addition to the fluid container parent element. Also remember that `sm-` effects only small dimensions (typically phones). And finally, check the div and set the display type to `block`

Comment: **[Something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/62q5bgsy/)**?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yeah I did actually do that, but I wanted the country and city text to stay on the left. I can probably style the text to be left though?

Comment: **[As in like this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/62q5bgsy/1/)**?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes, like that thanks. Someone also answered which also works.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following:

```
.input-control {
    border:none; /* Remove border bottom */
}

.dropdown, .dropup {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #696969; /* Add bottom border to drop down instead */
}

.dropdown-menu {
    width:100%; /* Make drop down 100% width OPTIONAL */
}
```

I put an optional 100% width on the drop down menu incase you wanted the border to match.

**UPDATE:**

Having the button full width would help usability as well.

```
.input-control {
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
}
```